# Histogram for data with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to make a histogram where the data live in periodic space but one bin intersects a boundary, that is, the leftmost and rightmost bins should be one and the same.

For example, if I have angular data that ranges from `0` to `360`, and would like to make `N`, `S`, `E`, and `W` bins, the `N` bin should include data from `0` to `45` *and* from `315` to `360`.  I can't do something like `np.histogram(data, bins=[315,45,135,225,315])` because `bins must increase monotonically`.

Of course, I could pretreat my data by 'rotating' it `data[data>bins.max()] -= 360` but that seems like kind of a hack and was wondering if there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.digitize`:

```
>>> a=np.random.randint(0,360,5000)
>>> ind=np.digitize(a,[45,135,225,315,360])
>>> np.bincount(ind)
array([ 616, 1246, 1268, 1249,  621])
# 0-45, 45-135, 135-225, 225-315, 315-360

>>> bins=np.bincount(ind)
>>> count=bins[:-1]
>>> count[0]+=bins[-1]
>>> count
array([1237, 1246, 1268, 1249])
```

Still kind of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
a = 360 * rand(5000)
look_up = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0])
ind = (a//45).astype(np.int8)
out = np.bincount(look_up[ind])
```

Basically you make a look-up array which has twice as many entries as you want bins (in your case).  You than integer divide your values by half the bin spacing you want to index into the lookup array (and we use numpy indexing magic to make this work).`np.bincount` than returns the number of times each bin is hit, which is the histogram you want.

You can also do this with `histogram` and some slicing tricks

```
a = 360 * rand(50000)

h, be = np.histogram(a, bins=8, range=(0, 360))  # 2x bins

h_p = np.sum(np.r_[h[-1], h[:-1]].reshape(-1, 2), axis=1) # rotate and sum
be_p = np.r_[np.r_[be[-2], be[:-2]][::2], be[-2]]         # rotate and skip
```

As a side note, it might be faster to do your shifting by

```
data_shifted = np.mod(data + 45, 360.0)
```